# Why Instance member 'getPerson' cannot be used on type 'GetPerson'

Tags: swift, frameworks

I write code in a Cocoa framework and call the function in it from main project. But it fails always returning a message. I fix this in two ways.

First, in main project viewController:

```
import getPerson

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        var person = GetPersons.getPerson(name: "Jack")
}
```

Returns:

> Instance member 'getPerson' cannot be used on type 'GetPerson'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead

Second:

```
import getPerson

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc = GetPersons.self
        var person = vc.getPerson(name: "Jack")
}
```

Returns:

> Instance member 'getPerson' cannot be used on type 'GetPersons'

What's happening with this? How do I fix it?

In test framework :

```
import Fundation 

public class GetPersons {

    public struct Person {

        public var name : String = ""
        public var age : Int = 0

    }

    public func getPerson(name : String) -> Person {
         var person = Person()
         return person
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your `GetPersons` class/struct and the `getPerson` method.

Comment: Updated ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, it's telling you that you defined getPerson(name: String) as an instance method. (Presumably because it operates on instance properties.)

You are calling it here as if it were defined as:

```
static func getPerson(name: String) { ...
```

The second is saying much the same thing, without guessing what you want to do.

If I understand what you want to do, I think it goes something like this:

```
class GetPersons {

    struct Person {

        public var name : String = ""
        public var age : Int = 0

    }

    func getPerson(name : String) -> Person {
         var person = Person()
         return person
    }
}
```

Then, in your view controller define a property for the instance of GetPersons:

```
let gp = GetPersons()
```

then in viewDidLoad:

```
let person = gp.getPerson(name: "Jack")
```

Also, is GetPersons in an actual framework, or is it simply a class defined (as it should be) in a separate file?

Comment: I update the method of the framework, I define it as a public function. How I fix  case 1?

Comment: @Edem This answer shows you how to fix it. Make the function `static`.

Comment: See addition to my answer above. Or what he said while I was typing,